# How to call CheckedChanged from MudCheckBox control

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

Please help me.

I do not find any CheckedChanged example for MudCheckBox. I got the results related to input control only.

```
<input type="checkbox" @onchange="HandleCheck" />
```

I tried the documents but didn't get exact example for **MudCheckBox**. I'm able to bind successfully to the IsCheckedTrue property. This checkbox is inside the MudTable. All I want to call **CheckedChanged** event.

```
<MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@context.IsCheckedTrue" Color="Color.Secondary" CheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.RadioButtonChecked" UncheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.RadioButtonUnchecked"></MudCheckBox>
```

Comment: If you make `IsCheckedTrue` a property you could work of off the setter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work using the new setters and getters.

```
<MudCheckBox @bind-Checked:get=context.IsCheckedTrue @bind-Checked:set=HandleCheck />

@code {
    private Task HandleCheck(bool value)
    {
        // Set the value in the model
        // Do what you want
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Or setting the parameters directly:

```
<MudCheckBox Checked=context.IsCheckedTrue CheckedChanged=HandleCheck />

@code {
    private Task HandleCheck(bool value)
    {
        // Set the value in the model
        // Do what you want
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You should also be able to do this, but there's been compiler problems with this syntax, so it may throw errors:

```
<MudCheckBox @bind-Checked=context.IsCheckedTrue @bind-Value:after="HandleAfter" />

@code {
    private Task HandleAfter()
    {
        // Do what you want
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's now "Task.CompletedTask" instead of Task.Completed.

Comment: A typo I'm afraid, it's always been `Task.CompletedTask`. I'm amazed I didn't get pulled up before!

Answer (score 2):

This works with standard mudblazor syntax

```
<MudCheckBox T="bool" Checked="CheckedVaribale" Label="Your Lable" CheckedChanged="@(e => OnCheckedChanged((bool)e))"></MudCheckBox>

public void  OnCheckedChanged(bool checkedvalue)
    {
        CheckedVaribale= checkedvalue;
        // do other stuff
    }
```

Comment: This works and I prefer this solution to the others.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way.

The MudSwitch is binded to the property ShowOnlyActiveItems with custom getter and setter

```
<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="@ShowOnlyActiveItems" Color="Color.Success" Label="Active only" Size="Size.Small" ></MudSwitch>
```

In the @code section:

```
private bool _showOnlyActiveItemsValue = true;
private bool ShowOnlyActiveItems { get { return _showOnlyActiveItemsValue; } set { _showOnlyActiveItemsValue = value; FilterOnStatus(value); } }
private void FilterOnStatus(bool value)
{
    ElementsToShow = Elements;
    if (value)
        ElementsToShow = ElementsToShow.Where(i => i.Status == (short)EntityStatusEnum.Active).ToHashSet();
}
```